# Binding Gridview by Eval in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ expression that joins two tables. I want to Bind 'List' to Gridview. the code makes this error in Gridview Template:
            **DataBinding: 'SearchResult' does not contain a property with the name 'codereq'.**

```
IQueryable<SearchResult> myList = from t in TBL_Apartment
    join k in TBL_Owner on t.Code equals k.Code
    where k.CodeReq == t.CodeReq

        select new SearchResult
        {
           codereq= t.CodeReq,
           name = t.Name
        }

public class SearchResult
{
    public string codereq;
    public string name;
}
```

Bind Gridview Code:

```
    GridSearch.DataSource = myList.ToList();
    GridSearch.DataBind();
```

as my aspx page for grid view is as below :

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="GridSearch" runat="server" Skin="Office2007" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        dir="rtl" Width="750px" GridLines="None" >

<MasterTableView>
<Columns>

<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Request Code" FilterControlWidth="100px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("codereq")==""?"0":Eval("codereq") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Owner Name" FilterControlWidth="100px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Lbl_Mahale" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")==""?"":Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

</Columns>
</MasterTableView>

<PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" />
<ClientSettings><Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" /></ClientSettings>

</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: Add a property aparteman to your SearchResult class

Comment: And better use string.empty instead of ""

Comment: @JohnnBlade sorry, I edited the code now

Comment: Have you checked if you are using the right datasource for your grid ?

Comment: @JohnnBlade error edited:  DataBinding: 'SearchResult' does not contain a property with the name **'codereq'**

Comment: Dont call your List List, can conflict with code rename it to myList or whatever

Comment: @JohnnBlade yes i checked the datasource. but i don't know why Eval can not find 'codereq' property

Comment: @JohnnBlade I changed the name of list but same error happens

Comment: Aint you supposed to use a variable here where k.CodeReq == ....

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
var myCodeReq = 1; (or some other type of variable)

    List<SearchResult> myList = (from t in TBL_Apartment join k in TBL_Owner on t.Code equals k.Code where k.CodeReq == myCodeReq select new SearchResult { codereq = t.CodeReq, name = t.Name }).ToList();

    GridSearch.DataSource = myList;
    GridSearch.DataBind();
```